# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (but it does)

Tags: php, oracle, laravel

I have a laravel application that has been working with my local oracle instance just fine. I added a migration for a new table, ran it and seeded it just fine. I started developing a repository for it the same way as my other repositories, but for some reason when I run phpunit on it gives me the ORA-00942 error. I even tried calling the seeder in phpunit and it gives the same error, which is odd because it worked fine when ran via artisan. At this point I'm at a loss, any ideas?

Migration (New table):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGoalTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('goal', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('patid')->unsigned();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('notes');
        $table->integer('progress');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->timestamp('target');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('goal');
}

}
```

Migration (Old working table)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDashTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dash', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('page');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->boolean('switchable');
        $table->integer('place')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('dash');
}

}
```

Sample Test:

```
public function testCurrentGoals()
{
    DB::connection('oracle_laravel')->table('dash')->delete(); //works fine
    DB::connection('oracle_laravel')->table('goal')->delete(); //error
}
```

Comment: are you using the same user? Which Oracle user is the owner of the table? Often it just means that a synonym or a privilege is missing to be able to see and/or access the table.

Comment: Checked the owner, same as all the other tables. I made an edit to show the migration for an older table and a test for both tables. One works the other doesnt. Ideas?

Comment: The owner might be the same as for a table that works, but are you connected as the same user (and to the same database!), and are you connected as the owner?

Comment: This lead me to the right answer. I was thinking this was more of a laravel thing, but it ended up being a phpunit config problem. Turns out another developer checked in a change to the default phpunit config file pointing it to a different db config file with a different username. Thanks!